# obter conteúdo do carrinho no woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Boa tarde pessoal!. EU queria obter os dados do carrinho de compras   no woocomerce. Quando eu acesso o array   no  descobri que   está protegido e não consigo acessa-lo para utilizar na minha página. Eu uso o código abaixo para obter os dados do carrinho:

```
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
```

foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $campo=> $value){

```
if(!empty($value['data']))
{ 
     var_dump($value['data']) 
}   
 
  
resultado do var_dump:
```

array(3) { [0]=> object(WC_Product_Simple)#15178 (12) { ["object_type":**protected**]=> string(7) "product" ["post_type":**protected**]=> string(7) "product" ["cache_group":**protected**]=> string(8) "products" ["data":**protected**]=> array(50) {

Comment: De acordo com a documentação do WC não existem métodos públicos para acessar esses atributos?

Answer (score -2):

Por favor, devore esse blog porque esse cara entende muito sobre woocommerce. É possível acessar tudo no core do que você imaginar e o que você não imaginar também é possível. Não desanime porque os ignorantes dão downvote na pergunta.

**WooCommerce: obter informações do pedido (total, itens, etc.) do objeto $ pedido**

**WooCommerce: Get Order Info (total, items, etc) From $order Object**

https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-easily-get-order-info-total-items-etc-from-order-object/

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Valeu irmão!!!!